# Was Twitter "Throttling" certain political tweets in 2017?

Tags: twitter

[Scott Adams](https://web.archive.org/web/20170206000110/https://blog.dilbert.com/post/156806516721/the-social-media-hive-mind) claimed in Feb 2017:

> You might have clicked on my misleading tweet to get to this page. I had to disguise the content so Twitter wouldn’t throttle it.
>
> Here’s why…
>
> This morning I tweeted a link to a great video that describes in detail how Twitter “throttles” the tweets of any content that disagrees with their political views. The video describes how Twitter gives a fake message that some tweets are no longer available, to discourage you from clicking to them. The tweets still exist, and you can access them by directly clicking the links in the tweets, but most people would not think to do that.

Scott Adams discusses a [NSFW<sup>1</sup> video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAAUD7jtFas) which accused Twitter of this behaviour.

The question is: Is Twitter throttling tweets of its users, as Scott Adams claims?

<sup>1 - contains foul language.</sup>

Comment: Related: [Does Twitter censor content with a double standard?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36024/does-twitter-censor-content-with-a-double-standard) It shouldn't be closed though ...

Comment: Is Scott Adams the author of the popular Dilbert  comic? Is that why this is notable?

Comment: @fredsbend. Yes, and a popular blog too

Comment: This is a legitimate question, but it's probably not answerable at this time because Twitter's algorithm is a trade secret.

Comment: @Avery:. Unless it can be shown that these glitches occur equally to all readers - e.g. they are caused by scaling issues on popular content rather than deliberate suppression.

Comment: @Ilya: Foul language, homophobia, borderline sexism, ad hominem attacks, etc.

Comment: @Oddthinking - there are numerous reports from people that Adams' posts don't show when they should - and indications are that this started when he started posting content complimentary to Trump on his posts (I refuse to use social media, so woudn't know how to tell one way or the other)

Comment: @user5341: Pure speculation: A post by a popular user, including Scott Adams, is going to be read by zillions of people. Rather than store it on a single server unable to keep up with the load, Twitter are going to duplicate it to caches around the world. The caching algorithm itself is going to get snowed under sometimes. So, sometimes when a user retweets a tweet, a message appears "Tweet is unavailable". Clicking on the tweet brings it up. I have seen this behaviour, and I am not a mover-and-shaker on Twitter, which was the video's claim. My point: Hanlon's Razor should be applied.

Comment: @Oddthinking You may be right. The issue is whether it is possible to distinguish between a "glitch" and deliberate action by Twitter's administrators.

Comment: Considering how many Nazi and other abusive accounts go unmoderated on Twitter, this is almost certainly a glitch.

Comment: @Oddthinking. We are talking days here, not minutes

Comment: Can we get a more formal definition of what "throttling" means in this context?  Because as a programmer to me it means "Slowing down request processing in order to cope with a backlog or to keep a service as a whole up and running even if some individual requests don't get serviced promptly".  By that definition, Twitter does and has throttled for years because they rate-limit the number of HTTP requests you can make

Comment: @GordonM  Yes, it's defined in the video.  I had made that clear in the original OP that Oddthinking edited.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees - are any of them notable with **tons** of followers?

Comment: I will say that I often have the devil's own time finding old tweets of mine in my profile. So it does look like there is some algorithm in there that picks and choses what old tweets of yours to show. However, unless @Jack there is a big Arsenal fan, its pretty clearly not done due to any content disagreement. So I suspect this is mostly some combo of a poorly understood algorithm and a few hyper-defensive users.

Comment: @fredsbend - IMHO this is definitely notable. I've heard this claim repeated on twitter a **lot**, going back months. I've tried looking into it myself several times, but its really hard to find a source about it that isn't Scott Adams himself, someone supporting him also using entirely circumstantial arguments, or a media piece doing nothing more than reporting his allegations.

Comment: @T.E.D. - the problem is that it seems to be done really intelligently, not a full ban (assuming it's intentional), making it **incredibly** difficult to prove due to algorithm not being public and thus not knowing expected behavior to test against. I'm tempted to message Adams and suggest specific testing strategies, but I don't actually use Twitter so my approaches would be very twitter-non-specific.

Comment: @user5341 - No, its not. In my experience, the tweets I can't find are almost entirely random (other than the fact that they happen to be the one I'm looking for of course, damnit). My guess is that he's just experiencing observer bias. The ones he doesn't care about he doesn't go looking for later (thus noticing they aren't being shown to him).

Comment: @T.E.D. - I haven't followed all details but my impression isn't that it's 1 user not seeing them but a large # of users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53208/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-user5341).

Answer (score 10):

In short, **No**.

Mr. Adams' complaint mirrors a common accusation by conservatives and boils down to two points:

1. "I am not getting the likes and engament I *believe I should be getting*."
2. "This is the result of deliberate sabotage of the algorithm to unfairly suppress my speech."

The so-called "Twitter Files" and the "expose" by Weiss that are [referenced in the other answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter_Files#No._2:_Visibility_filtering) get touted around a lot as "proof" for this, even though the actual contents disagree:

> Weiss characterized these practices as censorship and as evidence of
> shadow banning, which Twitter disputed, largely on the basis of its
> different definition of "shadow ban".[42] Twitter distinguished
> visibility filtering from shadow banning, which it defined as making
> "content undiscoverable to everyone except the person who posted
> it."[42][41]
>
> The documents Weiss discussed focused on individuals popular with the
> right-wing and suggested the moderation practices were politically
> motivated[39][41]—a long-standing claim among American
> conservatives,[42] which Twitter has denied.[38]
>
> **An internal study
> Twitter conducted in 2018 found its algorithms favored the political
> right**.[41][43][44]
>
> Wired and Slate described the policy by which
> moderators were unable to act on high-profile conservative accounts
> without first escalating to high-level management as "preferential
> treatment",[37][45] since this effectively limited Twitter's
> enforcement of their content policies on these accounts.[46]
>
> **Weiss did
> not reveal how many accounts overall were de-amplified nor the
> politics of those who were,[47] and this lack of context made it
> difficult to glean any conclusions on the matter**.[41]

If anything, this suggests that rather than "shadow-banning", high profile conservatives were handled with proverbial kid gloves and permitted to post comments that would get other people suspended or banned.

Comment: Yes, that is why US Judge has issued ruling against state agents. Because there is no interference from the state.

Comment: You state "no" at the top, then proceed to provide evidence on how the answer is "yes". Twitter, by taking action that effectively reduces the views a tweet receives is a "yes" answer to the OP.

Answer (score -8):

**was there 'visibility filtering'**

Yes, despite claims otherwise.

> We do not shadow ban.

[blog.twitter.com/](https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2018/Setting-the-record-straight-on-shadow-banning)

> Weiss contended that "visibility filtering" was merely Twitter's in-house term for "shadow banning".

Ref: [Twitter files (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter_Files#No._2:_Visibility_filtering) and [The free press](https://www.thefp.com/p/twitters-secret-blacklists)

**Was there ideological bias when it comes to content moderation?**

[The free press](https://www.thefp.com/p/twitters-secret-blacklists) seems to say yes.

> “They say they didn’t put their thumb on the scale,” Musk, who became CEO of Twitter in October, told The Free Press. “But they were pressing the thumb hard in favor of the left. If left, you could get away with death threats, and nothing would happen. If right, you could get suspended for retweeting a picture of a Trump rally.”

Other sources [Gizmodo](https://gizmodo.com/elon-musk-twitter-files-bari-weiss-part-two-shadow-ban-1849876635) [Forbes 1](https://www.forbes.com/sites/roberthart/2022/12/09/twitter-files-2-elon-musks-hyped-up-expos-unveils-secret-blacklists-and-shadow-banning--which-seem-very-similar-to-his-own-policies/)  and [Forbes 2](https://www.forbes.com/sites/roberthart/2022/12/09/twitter-files-2-elon-musks-hyped-up-expos-unveils-secret-blacklists-and-shadow-banning--which-seem-very-similar-to-his-own-policies/) dispute this claim.

Comment: The exact section you reference points out that Weiss' assertions were wrong - at best, a poor understanding of the facts; at worst, a deliberate misreading and partial release.

Comment: @Shadur That's news to me. If you have better reference, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: "An internal study Twitter conducted in 2018 found its algorithms favored the political right.[41][43][44] Wired and Slate described the policy by which moderators were unable to act on high-profile conservative accounts without first escalating to high-level management as "preferential treatment",[37][45] since this effectively limited Twitter's enforcement of their content policies on these accounts.[46]"

Comment: That's *in the exact document you're referencing*.

Comment: @Shadur I'm not following. The question is, roughly,  'are certain users held back', not 'are right-wing held back'.  2x Chapters at beginning seem to describe 'visibility filtering'. If that's not throttling, I don't know what is.

Comment: Scott's assertion was that Twitter *"throttles the tweets of any content that disagrees with their political views"*.