# Are Twitter censoring positive responses to President Trump's tweets?

Tags: politics, donald-trump, twitter

[This](http://www.infowars.com/is-twitter-censoring-positive-replies-to-donald-trumps-tweets/) article quotes Mike Keen saying,

> “The (anti-Trump) tweet that I replied to was deleted once mine started outpacing it in number of favorites and retweets. It was interesting to observe that once that tweet was deleted, mine stopped being interacted with. That’s because my tweet was no longer part of any “thread” in the conversation. Not a surprise, and nothing unusual about that. The only people who would see my comment are those who follow me already, which is a small number,” he writes.
>   “Over the past few days, I have continued to reply directly to the President, voicing my support of his policies and ideas. However, I have found that while initially, for about the first minute or so, I get a flood of reactions and notifications. Favorites, retweets, etc, and then they abruptly stop, because my tweets are being manually removed from the main conversation thread.”
>   “Every single Tweet by President Trump has top comments that are 100% negative. Positive replies are simply not seen. Twitter is absolutely censoring Pro-Trump replies and Trump supporters from voicing their support of the President,” he concludes.

Is there any possibility this is true? If so, is it documentably due to a flaw in the algorithm (i.e. people who disagree with Trump flag positive posts but people who agree with Trump don't flag negative posts), or is there evidence Twitter are pushing an agenda?

Comment: Related: [Is Twitter “Throttling” its users](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37118/is-twitter-throttling-its-users)

Answer (score 5):

**Information about Twitter's recent change, which could be seen as deliberately censoring positive responses:**

Earlier this month [Twitter changed](https://blog.twitter.com/2017/an-update-on-safety) their software to maximise quality content. In essence, this meant that replies to popular tweets were no longer ordered chronologically (i.e. the first reply is at the top), instead they are based upon the relevance and quality of the response (I imagine via retweets and favourites).

One could argue this is part of an agenda, or you could argue it was based on an existing design flaw that allowed anyone to game the system by programming responses to come in first. It's essentially now more like a Google search result system: "quality" results come first, not first comes first.

**Why this removes positive tweets (conjecture)**

I can't provide evidence why this makes the majority of responses appear negative. However, one could surmise that because Twitter is a medium with more [Democrats](http://adage.com/article/campaign-trail/facebook-republicans-twitter-democrats/295643/), it's logical that the majority of tweets and support for tweets would be negative towards Trump, and thus given a higher "quality" rating in the reply list.

Comment: Related from PC World: How to turn on Twitter's quality filters and silence trolls, http://www.pcworld.com/article/3109864/internet/how-to-turn-on-twitters-quality-filters-and-silence-trolls.html

Comment: I believe there is also a way to disable this feature if you prefer the old style, but I'm not sure of that as I don't use Twitter that much.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.  Why are "quality" tweets overwhelmingly negative?

Comment: According to the page you link, the new feature does not *sort tweets by quality*, it separates them into two separate categories. You can very clearly see in the animation that the "less relevant replies" are placed into a separate header.